# Can't get rid of "stale element" error while running my scrpt

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I've written a script in python with selenium. The script is supposed to click on some links in a webpage. When I run my script, It does click on the first link and then throws an error `stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document` instead of chasing for the next link. I searched a lot for the last few hours to find any solution to get rid of this error but no luck.

I'm not interested in their data so any solution other than the perocess of clicking is not what I'm looking for. How can I click on the links until the last link?

This is my attempt so far:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

def click_links(driver,url):
    driver.get(url)
    for olink in wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "result-row__item-hover-visualizer"))):
        olink.click()
        time.sleep(3)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    weblink = "https://www.hitta.se/s%C3%B6k?vad=Markiser+%26+Persienner"
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
    try:
        click_links(driver,weblink)
    finally:
        driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below code:

```
def click_links(driver,url):
    driver.get(url)
    links_len = len(wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "result-row__item-hover-visualizer"))))
    for index in range(links_len):
        cookies_bar = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[data-bind="visible: showCookieDialog"]')))
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].hidden='true';", cookies_bar)
        wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button[data-track="click-show-more"]'))).click()
        entry = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "result-row__item-hover-visualizer")))[index]
        entry.click()
        time.sleep(3)
        driver.back()
```

Comment: It's always a pleasure to come in contact with you sir Andersson. This is the best solution I've come across so far. The script is now running like a charm. However, after few clicking it throws another error `    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Element <span class="result-row__item-hover-visualizer">...</span> is not clickable at point (313, 559). Other element would receive the click: <span class="cookie-consent--text">...</span>`

Comment: ohh... ok. let me test it more thoroughly

Comment: Yeah, there is a div with query for accepting cookies. You can click OK button, but I just make it hidden. Now everything should work fine